# User input matching existing list

Tags: list, loops, input, match, user-input

I want user input to match an existing list and then do some loop stuff on the list they have chosen.

I've tried to get the user to input something and ideally that matches an existing list name. I want to save this input (and therefore list) as a new name.

```
ListA = [1, 2, 3]
ListB = [4, 5, 6]

UserList = input("What list would you like to choose?")
```

Here I want the user to type ListA or ListB and then that list be renamed as UserList. It's here I seem to be having problems!!

Then UserList gets put through some looping stuff...

```
For x in UserList:
if x == ...blah blah blah
```

I'd like the user input to pick an existing list and it be renamed. But this isn't happening. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

from what I understood, you want the list UserList to have either the elements of ListA or ListB, so the following should work

```
ListA = [1, 2, 3]
ListB = [4, 5, 6]
UserList = input("What list would you like to choose?")
if UserList == 'ListA':
    UserList = ListA
if UserList == 'ListB':
    UserList = ListB
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Assuming the name you want to rename it by is 'UserList'?